# Show system "working" animation in NETCF

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5, .net-cf-3.5

I would like to programmatically show and hide the built-in "working" animation from Windows Mobile. I am talking about the rotating colored brushes you can see in the middle:
[image]

Yes, I know that I could make my own animation, but this would be completely satisfying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

to show the wait animation.

In most cases an

```
 Applications.DoEvents();
```

will help, if the cursor does not change immediately.